# How to read CR LF line with BufferedReader?

Tags: java, newline, bufferedreader

I am trying to create a simple java server application, but I am struggling to read the user's input with BufferedReader correctly.
The problem is that the line delimeter is CR LF ("\r\n") only - so I can't use readLine() standard method. Therefore, I tried to implement my own method:

```
private String readCRLFLine(BufferedReader in) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    char cr = 'a'; // initialize cr
    char lf;

    try {
        while (((lf = (char) in.read()) != '\n') && (cr != '\r')) {
            cr = lf;
            result.append(lf);
        }
        result.deleteCharAt(result.length() - 1); // delete \r from the result
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle the exception here
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Now, when I try to get and print the result:

```
while ((userMessage = readCRLFLine(inputStream)) != null) {
        System.out.println(userMessage);
        break;
}
```

...it only prints the sequence of characters to the first break line character ("\r" or "\n") and the rest of the input is read by the second call of method
readCRLFLine(inputStream) - which should already read other input.

I want to be able to handle inputs like:

> "abc\rabc\n\r\abc\r\n"

In this case userMessage should be:

> "abc\rabc\n\r\abc"

I can't use Scanner and it's "useDelimeter("\r\n")" method, because I need to set up TIMEOUT with "clientSocket.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT)" and from what I know, this is not possible with Scanners.

What is wrong with my "readCRLFLine" method? Is there any other solution to this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that BufferedReader.readLine() doesn't support CRLF? It does. Also, whether you read from a Socket InputStream with a Scanner or with any other class doesn't change anything to the ability of setting a timeout on the socket.

Comment: From javadoc for BufferedReader.readLine(): "A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed." My line is only delimited by "\r\n" -> therefore "\n" and "\r" should not be considered as newline.

Comment: @Filco28 so if a line has a lone `\n` or `\r` in it you want that to be considered one line.  NOTE: most text editors honour this so what you are describing is not a normal text file.

Comment: BTW In your loop, you won't be able to tell if one line has a \n in it or there was two lines. i.e. your use case doesn't demonstrate why you need this.

Comment: You mean that you're using \r, or \n, in the middle of a line? Why oh why?

Comment: BTW a `while` loop with a `break;` at the end is the same as an `if` block.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know it is not a normal text file - it is a part of a school project. I need to iterate through the resultMessage and get the ASCII value of each character from the input - that is why I want to be able to handle a lone '\r' or '\n' as a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is incorrect because the `while` condition is not what you actually need.

It says "As long as the currently read character is different than `\n` **and** the previous character is different than `\r`, continue reading".

But that means that when you read a `\n`, that condition is *false*, because `lf != '\n'` is false. So it will stop on the first `\n`. It will also stop on any character that follows a `\r`, because then `cr != '\r'` is going to be `false` making the combined condition false.

You want to stop the loop when the current character is `\n` and the previous character is `\r`. That means your while condition is supposed to be`! ( lf == '\n' && cr == '\r')`.

Now pay attention to the DeMorgan law: "not (A and B)" is equivalent to "not A **OR** not B". You mistakenly decided to use AND instead of OR. Change your condition to:

```
while (((lf = (char) in.read()) != '\n') || (cr != '\r')) {
   ...
}
```

By the way, you should probably check that the value you read from `in` is not negative before you convert it to `char` and compare it. A negative value indicates that the client closed the connection, and you'll get into an endless loop if that happens.

Comment: Yes, of course "&&" was the problem. Not sure why I missed it. Thank you for your help. I will check the value before converting as well.